# In CAKEPHP Check content of all view and send mail if not ok

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.9

With cakephp 2.9 I have this need:

I should check if there is a specific tag on the page that appears.

if it is present, must not do anything else must send me an email.

At this point I think to create a helper and recall a method in the **default.ctp**

with something like:

```
$s = this-> fetch (‘content’);
$result_check = $this->myHelper->debug_content ($s); 
echo $s;
```

In the **myHelper** the function:

```
public function debug_content( $s) { 
  $pos = strpos ( $s, "<div class = \"box-body\">"); 
  if ( $pos === false) { echo “Error tag is not present!”; 
  return false; 
}
```

In the **AppController**:

```
public $helpers = array (…, ‘myHelper’);
```

and up to here ok … but now?

How do I recall the component Email (personalized by me) to send an email?

And where do I call it?

How would you do?

Thank you,

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if I got your question right. But you can implement the needed e-mail sending  function into your function where you are checking for the tag.

```
 App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');

public function debug_content( $s) { 
  $pos = strpos ( $s, "<div class = \"box-body\">"); 
  if ( $pos === false) { echo “Error tag is not present!”; 
 $Email = new CakeEmail();
 $Email->emailFormat('html');
 $Email->template('default');
 $Email->from('sending@adress.com');
 $Email->to('receiving@adress.com');
 $Email->subject('YOUR SUBJECT');
 $Email->send();
  return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Implement](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#registering-listeners) a listener for the `View.afterRenderFile` event and see if this solves the issue. Have a look at the source code of the `View` class, [you can see](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/View/View.php#L935) that this callback receives the view file name and the evaluated contents during the call to `View::render()`. You can then use this listener to check the contents for your tag and send that email if necessary.